# Power BI Report Server: You are not allowed to view this folder

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

Hello I have installed Power BI Report Server and set it up on my local sql server db.

I am successfully able to launch my web portal page but I get this error below:

[image]

How can I resolve this?? It seems I am logged in with the same account that has the admins rights to the local db. itself. Any help on this matter would be great.

Thanks,
Wajahat Kayani